# Is it possible to make a property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, overloading

I want to make a custom `Array` object that recieves a number as index, and depending on the value of the index, it would return a computed value.

For example:

```
>>> var MyArray(2);
>>> MyArray[2];
4
>>> MyArray.2;
4
```

I know that for the showed example, I'm better of with a function, but I want to know if I can override the properties/index lookup for some things that are conceptualy arrays, but could need some computation.

I'm aware that `x.1 == x[1]`, so what I need is to make a property in javascript.

I mean, make `x.variable = x.myPropery()`, so everytime that I get the value of `x.variable`, I recieve the return of `x.myPorperty()`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [Javascript Getters and Setters are possible](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) only on

- Firefox
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9.5+

Internet Explorer (in any of it versions) is lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

variable[property] is the same as dot notation so you are doing MyArray.2, which is a variable, not a method that gets evaluated.  You can't really do what you want without a method that either changes the property when it is assigned, or a method that computes the right value when you pull it out.

And no, you cannot override [], its simply dot notation, its not really an index that you can override

Re: your comment, Absolutely, you can do

```
var x = new Array();
x[1] = function () { alert('x') };

var myFunction = x[1];

x[1]();        // alerts "x"
myFunction();  // alerts "x"

alert(x[1]);         // alerts "function () { alert('x') };"
alert(myFunction);   // alerts "function () { alert('x') };"
```

Comment: I am aware of `x[1] == x.1`. Is there a way to make `x.i == x.myProperty()`?

Comment: I've since addressed that in the post, remember, you can declare and pass functions around and you can call them and get their results, but you cannot call a function without ()

Comment: I guess I've not explained myself correctly. I know that functions can be asigned, but can a property like Python's, .NET's be done, instead of Java's getters and setters?

Comment: You want a C# style getter like: 

int MyProperty get { return computed_value; }; ?

If so, no you cant do that